# inside page css cancels effects of dotless reference in asp .net mvc

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, dotless

When I don't use inner page style, dotless style* works perfectly. *But, when I use inner page style(nothing else changed), inner page style works but dotless style doesn't work anymore.* Is this a bug, or is there a solution?

*What I mean with "dotless style" is the style of .less file referenced by page.

**Inner page style**:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .detailRow {
            border: 1px solid burlywood;
        }
</style>
```

**Dotless file reference**:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/_Stil/Ortak/TableFormat.less")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: What is "dotless" style? Your CSS is fine.

Comment: "dotless" style is the style inside .less file referenced by page. The style shown above is in the page. Inside page style kills the effects of dotless style file.

Comment: Are you modifying a class that is present in the dotless file?

Comment: What type of html? I edited the question, I hope it is more understandable now.

Comment: No, I didn't modify a class in dotless file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the css in the referenced dotless file is working fine without the on page styling and then after adding the style tag it stops to work I have to make a few assumptions..

Since you say that only one of them can work at the same time I assume that they are overriding each other.

Like if you have the exact same css class in your less file and then add a style tag on your page you might override the css class in the file (depending on the markup in the file ofc). This might give the illusion that the css class in the less file have stopped working.

I suggest that you scope the css class in the less file with an id or something like that to give it more specificity and see what happens. Else you should show some content from the less file and some HTML markup of the page.

Comment: In my experience on page styling stopped referenced dotless style; it didn't override.